# What do all of these pictures have in common?

Tags: word, pattern, visual, word-property

[image: What do all of these pictures have in common]

**What do all of these things have in common?**

The answer is a simple word or phrase.

Comment: They are square. (Edit: first you say "pictures", then you say "things")

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All of these pictures are linked by the word:

> **BLACK**

As we can have:

> [Blacklight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklight)
>  [Black Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Forest)
>  [Black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole)
>  Blackboard
>  [Blackjack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackjack)
>  [Blackpool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackpool)
>  Blackberries
>  [Black Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sea)
>  Blackmail

Comment: Fourth one is a rot13(obneq)

Comment: @eyl327 Ah yes, I can see that now! Thanks - amended :)

Answer (score 3):

They all reflect the concept of **time**.

A lightbulb is a symbol of the humanity's progress through time; it's an artificial image of sun, the one thing that guides us through the day.

A forest is a unit of time, 17 seconds or so.

The hole in the tree is a circle, quite like a clock. That wood, when put vertically, has a shadow that tells us the time.

Number 12, midnight and noon.

A pool has water, and water moves, just like time.

Fruits take time to be edible.

The ocean has waves, the foundation of this world is in waves, yet time lives outside of that.

Bills have to be paid on time.

Comment: Bit of a stretch - I think you'd be hard-pressed to find an image that *couldn't* somehow be connected to the concept of time.

Comment: Also the value of a Jack is 11 (10, J, Q, K = 10, 11, 12, 13).

Answer (score 3):

I think they all have The letter 'O' in common.

- Lamppost
- The woods (Forest)
- Hole
- Wood
- Joker
- Pool
- Morango(strawberry)
  Mirtilo (blueberry)
  [in portuguese]
- Ocean
- Mailbox